# Ember Router - multilevel resource

Tags: ember.js

Apollogies for my english,

I have a router like this :

```
App.Router.map ()->
@resource 'movies' , ->
  @route 'free'
  @route 'featured'
  @route 'index'
  @route 'movie', path: '/:movie'

@resource 'seasons' , ->
  @route 'free'
  @resource 'featured', ->
    @route 'season', path : '/:season'
  @route 'index'
  @route 'season', path: '/:season'
```

In this particular case:

```
@resource 'seasons' , ->
  @route 'free'
  @resource 'featured', ->
    @route 'season', path : '/:season'
```

If a do a :

```
{{#linkTo "seasons.featured.season" 25}} ....
```

Ember throws an exception. I have to do :

```
{{#linkTo "featured.season" 25}} .... // this way is ok
```

The same with the templates. I Have to put in the path:

```
/templates/featured/seasson.hbs  // ok
```

Instead of how i think should be the correct path:

```
/templates/seasons/featured/seasson.hbs // worng
```

Is this the correct way ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way. Have a look at this [part of the router guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources). If you nest `resources`, the path of the route is "reset".

The following example is from the guide:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
    this.resource('comments', function() {
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

You would link the new route for comments like this:

```
{{#linkTo "comments.new"}}
```

Accordingly the template would have to be named `comments/new`.

But if you wish, **you can preserve the namespacing**, which is also explained in the guide:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('foo', function() {
    this.resource('foo.bar', { path: '/bar' }, function() {
      this.route('baz'); // This will be foo.bar.baz
    });
  });
});
```

Now the full route name of baz is `foo.bar.baz` and the template would have to be placed in `foo/bar/baz`.

Comment: Then close the question, if you are happy :-)

Comment: I was just about to post the updated part of your answer :) but you where very fast :)

Comment: I asked myself, why this is the case and i just read through this part in the guides :-). But most of the time you are incredibly fast :-)

Comment: thank guys, i had to wait 10 minutes to close the question, you were very fast !! :D